# Bootstrap4 compatibility with IE and Edge - Nav dropdown and video tag issues

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, html5-video

I've made my first website, and I've run into some issues that I cannot solve myself.
The website is Bootstrap 4.

https://jsfiddle.net/NUJ88/cn2bdrw1/ <-- My nav

1: My main issue is compatibility with IE and Edge (Possibly also Firefox). Everything works fine in Chrome.

When I open it in IE11 the nav dropdowns aren't target-able and wont stay open on click. How do I solve this?

2: My second issue is the fullscreen html5 video function, which wont display on IE11 or Edge.

HTML:

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="homeVideo">
     <source src="./local-source-mp4-file" type="video/mp4"; codecs="H.264/MPEG-4">
     Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

CSS:

```
#homeVideo {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: transparent url(video-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

video {
  display: block;
}

.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -100;
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is not compatible with the old IE8/9. Bootstrap 4 is working fine in IE10/11, Edge, FF, Chrome, etc.  Still there are differences in the look of some components like buttons and form fields but that is not about the functionalitty. The nav ddropdown is working ok in all browsers. The html5 video tag is a terrible component to style in a way that it looks the same in all browsers.

Comment: "The html5 video tag is a terrible component to style in a way that it looks the same in all browsers" 
If that is the case then how should I go about getting a full screen video, that will autoplay, muted and fullscreen in most modern browsers?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job. The css is responsive so the video keeps its 16:9 ratio on all screen formats. It is not possible to have full width **and** full height because a video is 16:9 and many screens are not.

If you do not support Opera older then version 25 then you can remove the `type="video/ogg"` line. All modern browsers support `type="video/mp4"`.

Note that the `width="320" height="180"` in the `<video>` tag are doing nothing. The css sets width and responsive height.

The styling of the `<video>` is terrible. For example, it is not possible to change icons, change button shape, etc. etc. For syling, a Javascript player is required, lik jPlayer http://jplayer.org

Trying to automatically execute the video to full screen (like the full screen button on the video player) is not possible. Even with the Javascript 'requestFullscreen' method it will result in an error `Video API can only be initiated by a user gesture`. In other words, the full screen can only be started by the website visitor with, for example, a button in the html.

```
<body>
  <div class="videoContainer">
    <video width="320" height="180" autoplay controls muted>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
  </div>
</body>
```

with this css to keep the 16:9 ratio on all screen formats

```
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.videoContainer {
  display: block;
  width: 100%; /* width of video */
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.videoContainer::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  padding-top: 56.25%; /* keep 16:9 ratio */
}
.videoContainer video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: This didnt solve it for me. It gave me a small thumbnail video in Edge and nothing in IE. 

I've chosen to go with a polyfill to solve this issue. I know its not the ideal solution, but hey if I dont use too many -_-

I went with this https://github.com/TricomB2B/object-fit-videos 

Implementation explained (for other newbies like me) here: https://youtu.be/VpFTj3Q7DVM